# How can I block access to the internet for static addresses?

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, dhcp

I have a router on CentOS 7 which provides access to internet for several IP addresses, which are reserved at DHCP server. Other hosts are blocked. If someone put static address from the reservation range, obviously, he would gain internet access. How can I distinct a static address from leased by DHCP one, and block it?
The list of hosts which need to access the internet is not static, so it would be good to have a handy way to manage them.

Comment: What is your reason for wanting to do this? Or, in other words, what is it you are really trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can try "dnsmasq" software in order to get what you want: you need to define the list of IPs to be provided (https://sfxpt.wordpress.com/2013/11/30/dnsmasq-installation-configuration-5/#static) with MAC binding, and then tell dnsmasq to ignore all "unknown" clients (http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq.conf.example option "dhcp-ignore")